# jQuery function "on()" working in Firefox but not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works in Firefox but not in Chrome. Alert is executed only in Firefox. Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#myselect option').on('click', function() { 
            var selectvalue= $(this).attr('value');
            alert(selectvalue);
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using? A jsFiddle.net example would help too.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to bind events to the `option`s because the handling will be inconsistent - if someone uses the keyboard arrows to select their option, will the `.click` event fire?

You're probably better off just binding `$('#myselect').on('change', function...` which will catch any time the value is changed for any reason.

Comment: Here's a quick demo I threw together to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRCtN/

Comment: Thanks, but how can I then change `var selectvalue= $(this).attr('value');` ? This is not working `var selectvalue= $(this).('option').attr('value');`

Comment: ok, thanks, seems to be working in Chorme too ;)